# CentOSをバージョンアップする手段を知りたい

Tags: centos, vagrant, virtualbox

VirtualBox＋vagrant+CentOS6で構築している開発環境から
CentOS7.5に移したいのですが経験がなく疑問が出ました。

自分なりにパターンとしてやり方を考えてみたのですが
お勧めの環境移動方法などご教授いただけましたら幸いです。

##### パターン１

CentOSディストリビューションをバージョンアップするのは
６と７で結構な違いがあるので大変そうだなという印象でした。
[CentOS を 6 から 7 にアップグレードしてみた。 | みむらの手記手帳](http://mimumimu.net/blog/2014/07/14/centos-%E3%82%92-6-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-7-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F%E3%80%82/)

##### パターン２

現在CentOS7.2での環境は別プロジェクトで作っていたので
そちらをコピーして7.2→7.5とし、
（マイナーアップデートであれば影響は少ないでしょうか？）
サイトごとのディレクトリをFTPソフトなどで移動。
この時ホストOSがwindowsのためnode_modulesディレクトリがきれいに
移動できるかが不安ですが。
vagrant間で直接移動させる仕組みなど検索してみたのですが
情報にたどり着けませんでした。

##### 開発環境

開発環境はよくあるウェブサイト用環境です。
Apache（バーチャルホスト使用）
PHP
MySQL
WordPress
Git
gulp.js
Node.js
npm
nvm
Sass
上記のツールに関してもバージョンを最新安定板にしたいと考えています。

virtualboxのNIC設定は
virtualboxのguiツール→設定→ネットワーク→アダプター2タブで確認すると
割り当ての項目にホストオンリーアダプターと設定されています。
プロンプトで確認するとイーサネット アダプター VirtualBox Host-Only Network #
となっています。（移動元centos6、移動先centos7共に）

#### 質問

- CentOS の7.2→7.5などマイナーアップデートのご経験談がありましたら伺いたいです。
- vagrantプロジェクト内、特定ディレクトリのデータを簡単に移動する方法があれば知りたいです。
- 前述の2パターン以外のお勧めの方法があればご教授いただけましたら幸いです。

Comment: 念のため確認させてください。既存のゲストOSとしては`CentOS6`と`CentOS7`の二つがあり、「CentOS6を7に直接アップグレード」か「既存のCentOS7をマイナーアップデート、必要なデータのみCentOS6から移行」の2パターンで検討している、ということでしょうか？もう1点、「開発環境」というのが具体的にはどんなものかも詳しく書いておくとアドバイスが付きやすいと思います。

Comment: cubickさん、記事の修正、コメントありがとうございます！パターンについてはおっしゃる通り2パターンでどちらが楽そうか、スムーズにいきそうかということで検討しています。開発環境も追記しました。

Comment: VirtualBoxのVMで、NICの設定は「ホストオンリーアダプタ」でしょうか？

Comment: take88さんコメントありがとうございます！NIC設定の設定を調査して追記してみました。もし見当違いのことを調査していましたら突っ込んでいただけましたら幸いです。何かわかりましたらまたコメントお願いいたします。

Comment: 改めて検索したところ以下で行けそうな感じもしたので一度バックアップをとって試してみます！https://qiita.com/areaz_/items/c9075f7a0b3e147e92f2
バックアップに時間がかかりそうなのでいったん質問を閉じさせていただきます。コメントいただきましてありがとうございましたm(_)mまた不明点が出ましたら質問を立てさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

改めて検索したところ以下で行けそうな感じもしたので一度バックアップをとって試してみます！

[VirtualBoxを使って２つのゲストOS間で通信してみる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/areaz_/items/c9075f7a0b3e147e92f2)

バックアップに時間がかかりそうなのでいったん質問を閉じさせていただきます。
コメントいただきましてありがとうございましたm(_)m
また不明点が出ましたら質問を立てさせていただきます。